# PHP: is for($i < $n) loop necessary?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a 2d array, part of which looks like this($arr is the main array):

```
    $arr = array(
        array("id" => "61","name"   => "Алла","surname" => "Сарычева","patronymic" => "Игоревна","math" => "45","russian" => "69","informatics" => "56",),
        array("id" => "63","name"   => "Элина","surname" => "Ахильгова","patronymic" => "Алисхановна","math" => "33","russian" => "73","informatics" => "52")

)
```

There are about 500 sub-arrays in the main array, and I only want to output the `$n` amount of them. I would like to know if for-loop is the best decision for this problem or there are some weird `array_map` manipulations or something like that which allow to perform the task faster than using the for-loop.

Thanks all of you a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by output the $n amount of them?

Comment: Do you want to capture the first $n elements?

Answer (score 0):

You want to slice an array by an `$n` parameter. Thus, you may use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
$output = array_slice($arr, 0, $n);
```

where `0` represents the offset and `$n` the length.